# vuetify v-card only two rounded corners

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to have a v-card where only two corners are rounded. I tried the following but it didn't work (the card is rotated by 90°).

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div class="text-center rotate-ninety ml-n6">
          <v-card 
            hover 
            ripple 
            class="rounded-card py-5 px-2" 
            elevation="10" 
            color="orange" 
          >
              <v-icon 
                color="black" 
                left
              >
                mdi-domain
              </v-icon>
              <span class="black--text">
                Domain
              </span>            
            </v-card>               
          </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rotate-ninety {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}

.rounded-card {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Do i miss something?

Thanks a lot
Chris

Comment: Do you get any rounding at all?

Comment: Is your css scoped?

Comment: I didn't get your question... can u clarify?

Comment: I want a v-card which has two perfectly 90° corners and two corners are rounded. But I can't change the basic shape of all v-cards since I use several v-cards on my side. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vuetify's own [in-built helper classes for border radius](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/).

To achieve a top-rounded card:
`<v-card tile class="rounded-tr rounded-tl">`

Comment: Hey Anzu Pai, that solution is even better. I used the following code: <v-card tile class="rounded-r-xl">. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Try to override the `.v-sheet.v-card` class rule like :

```
.rounded-card .v-sheet.v-card {
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/VwbyBjy)

Comment: Hey Boussadjra Brahim, thannks! That works perfectly fine but I use several v-cards on my side and I only want one to look like this with the two rounded corners. Do you know how I can realize this for only one specific v-card?

Comment: in style section of the component add scoped attribute like `<style scoped>.v-sheet.v-card {..}</style>`

Comment: Thanks! This will limit the effect to one specific .vue page but since I use several v-cards in one .vue page (index.vue) I change all the look of all the v-cards in the index.vue what I don't want. I want to change only the look of one specific v-card in one secific .vue page (index.vue). Hope that explains it a bit better. Sorry that I dodn't explain that before.

Comment: Try out `.rounded-card .v-sheet.v-card{...}`